# Separate javascript object into groups with 4 items in the click event

Tags: javascript

How do I split a javascript object into groups with 4 items each group? follows an example of how the array or object should stay, but I would like to know how I can create a function so that when the user clicks a button, 4 of those items are displayed in the html .. when clicking again it should display 4 more until it has not more items to display! Thank you.

```js
var obj = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4',
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    'item11'
]

console.log(obj.slice(0, 4));    
console.log(obj.slice(4, 8));
console.log(obj.slice(8, 12));
```

Comment: So hold a variable with index zero and read the 4 items. When next is clicked, you add 4 and read the next four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  Just change `.slice()` to `.splice()`.  Check `obj.length` if you want to add a sanity check for data, but it fails gracefully if there's no data left and just returns nothing.

```js
var obj = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4',
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    'item11'
]

console.log(obj.splice(0, 4));    // removes & returns the first 4 elements
console.log(obj.splice(0, 4));    
console.log(obj.splice(0, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer helped me, in the simplest way, well this I needed.

Comment: No worries - glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would work? Keep the index in the global scope so you can persist the value between click events. Print groups would be the function to call in your click handler (modification obviously needed)

```js
var arr = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4',
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    'item11'
];

//builds the groups of 4 from arbitrary length array
function buildGroups(arr){
  var groupedArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(groupedArr[Math.floor(i/4)] === undefined){
      groupedArr[Math.floor(i/4)] = [];
    }
    groupedArr[Math.floor(i/4)].push(arr[i]);
  }
  return groupedArr;
}

//get grouped version
var groupedArr = buildGroups(arr);
//init group index
var groupIndex = 0;

function printGroup(){
  if(groupedArr[groupIndex]){
    //do something with group here
    console.log(groupedArr[groupIndex]);
  }else{
    //no more groups
  }
  groupIndex++;
}

printGroup();
printGroup();
printGroup();
printGroup();
```

I Liked the pre-processing above because it's more portable.. but depending on your use case a cleaner way to architect the code could be without the pre-grouping step:

```js
var arr = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4',
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    'item11'
];

var index = 0;

function printGroup(){
  if(arr[index]){
    //do something with group here
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      if(arr[index] !== undefined){
        console.log(arr[index]);
      }
      index++;
    }
    console.log('groupEnd');
  }else{
    //no more groups
  }
}

printGroup();
printGroup();
printGroup();
printGroup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of thr current page:

```
var page = 0, size = 4;
```

Them just iterate over that page:

```
for(var index = page * size; index < obj.length && index < (page + 1) * size; index++) {
 console.log(obj[index]);
}
```

To get the next / previous page just increase / decrease page and let the loop run again.